# PHP - forwardslash between main page and subpages

Tags: php, parent-child, slash

Wondering how to have a forward slash between a main page and its subpages.

**Current outcome**
mywebsite.com/page1-subpage.php

**Desired outcome:**
mywebsite.com/page1/subpage.php

When trying to use a slash in this bit of code gives me an error message: "/".$page->url

**Full code below**

```
if($page->parent > 1){
    $l = getParentById($page->parent,$pages);
    $page->url = remove_accents($l->title)."-".$page->url;
    }
```

When using the original "_" or a "-", everything works just fine.

Can somebody help me out please? I guess this quite an easy issue. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**
Additional code. Hope this makes some sense.

```
if(!$page->title){
    PError("Please fill in a page title.");
    }
    $page->type = sprintf("%s",Utilities::scrub($_POST['type']));
    $page->url = sprintf("%s",Utilities::scrub($_POST['url']));


if($page->type=='page'){
    $page->url = remove_accents($page->title).".php";


if($page->parent > 1){
    $l = getParentById($page->parent,$pages);
    $page->url = remove_accents($l->title)."/".$page->url;
    }
//print_r($page);
//exit;

if((!$page->id)&&(file_exists("../".$page->url))){
    PError("Page title already exists. Please choose another title.");
    exit();
    }
}

if($page->type == 'link'){

if(!$page->url){
    PError("Fill in a URL.");
    }

}

$page->display = sprintf("%s",Utilities::scrub($_POST['display']));

$new=0;
if(!$page->id){
    $page->id = uniqid();
    $new=1;
    }

if(SaveHeaderImage($page->id)){
    $page->headerimage = sprintf("%s",Utilities::scrub($_FILES['headerimage']['name']));
    }

if($new){
    array_push($pages,$page);
}
else{

    foreach($pages as &$l){
        if($l->id == $page->id){
            $l = $page;
            break;
            }
        unset($l);
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT 2: Function**

```
function remove_accents($string)
{

$table = array(
    'Š' => 'S', 'š' => 's', 'Ð' => 'Dj', 'ð' => 'dj', 'Ž' => 'Z', 'ž' => 'z', '?' => 'C', '?' => 'c', '?' => 'C', '?' => 'c',
    'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'A', 'Ç' => 'C', 'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'e',
    'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I', 'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I', 'Ñ' => 'n', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O',
    'Õ' => 'O', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ø' => 'O', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Þ' => 'B', 'ß' => 'Ss',
    'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a', 'ä' => 'a', 'å' => 'a', 'æ' => 'a', 'ç' => 'c', 'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e',
    'ê' => 'e', 'ë' => 'e', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i', 'ð' => 'o', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o',
    'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'o', 'ø' => 'o', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u', 'û' => 'u', 'ý' => 'y', 'ý' => 'y', 'þ' => 'b',
    'ÿ' => 'y', '?' => 'R', '?' => '?',
);

$string = strtr($string, $table);
$string = strtolower($string);
$string = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9/]+#', '-', $string);
$string = trim($string, '-');       
return $string; 
}
```

Comment: That should work, there must be some other issue with your code somewhere further down the line.

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: @Revent Thanks for your replies. I'm getting an internal server error. Strange enough, when using a dash "-" or underscore "_", everything is working fine.

Comment: Can you print the value of `$page->url` at this point in the code? It may not be what you expect.

Comment: @Braunson. Not sure what you mean there Revent. Completely new to the game. I've just edited my post above with some additional info. May make some sense.

Comment: I mean what's the value of `print_r($page->url);` at that point when you get the error? Also, what does the `Utilities::scrub` function do?

Comment: The error shows when trying to open a subpage of a page. So mywebsite.com/page1/subpage1. I can open the frontpage, page 1, but next I can't open the subpage 1 in the browser. No problems with creating the pages..

Comment: @Revent. Just added the function as well. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of that the slash in URL means that there is a directory - which is "page1" in your case - and the web server is trying to find the sub-pages inside that directory.

If that is the case, you have two options: 
1. Create that directory "page1" and put your code inside it and try to access the sub-pages.
2. Or configure your web server by adding rewrite rule to redirect all requests to your main page.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. Ok, sounds logic. I guess there's no standard/universal rewrite rule to redirect pages to a subpage structure based on forward slash mapping?